# Как у тысяч удалить знаки после запятой, а у десятков оставить их?

Tags: php

Обрабатываю полученное число таким образом

```
    $sr_price = number_format($p / $current_sr_price, 3);
```

На входе получаю число 0.055628885141852, а на выходе 0.055

и второй вариант с большим числом, на входе 2126.4424673902, а на выходе 2,126.442

Как большее число привести к формату  2,126?

Спасибо!

Comment: Чем именно характеризуется большее число?

Comment: Знаками до точки, больше 0.

Comment: Ну так и сравни - если число меньше единицы - один формат, больше - другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда, допустим, так:

```
$num = $p / $current_sr_price;
if ($num < 1){
    $sr_price = number_format($num, 3); 
} else {
    $sr_price = number_format($num, 0);
}
```

Comment: @u_mulder а, ну да, похоже на то.

Comment: Спасибо, все четко работает! Буду знать теперь, как с цифрами работать....

Comment: $current_sr_price может быть равна 0